# Oracle SQL, Can't Figure Out Left Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have 2 tables:

`Person` table with column `person_id`

`Employee` table with columns `emp_type` = `full` or `part`

I need a query that returns everyone in `Person`, but exclude full time employees. What I'm struggling with is not all Persons are necessarily in `Employee` table.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Please show your actual table structure, and ideally some sample data.

Comment: @Kritner That would assume that an employee can only have one designation, which we don't really know, because the OP posted no real table structure or data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, that's why i only did a comment :)

Comment: But I misread the question anyway bahaha

Comment: Is this homework? What did you already try?

Comment: I already tried left join where emp_type = 'part', but it's not filtering out full time employees.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below, but you didn't give us your tables structure so I can only guess what do you mean here.

```
select * 
from person p
left join employee e on p.person_id = e.person_id
where p.emp_type <> 'full'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your full query or table structure information, you'll need to make adjustments. But using a `not exists` clause is probably the most straight forward way of doing this.

```
select p.*
  from person p
 where not exists (select null
                     from employee e
                    where e.person_id = p.person_id
                      and e.emp_type = 'full')
```